# Resetting radiobutton function after every selection

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I am wondering how I would go about resetting the application when someone makes another selection. When you run my code you will see that when I choose a genre it works fine but if I select another one it runs another instance in the same window. I want the user to be able to cycle through genres and see different movies.

```
from tkinter import *

class movie1:
def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    master.title("Movie Recommendation")

    self.label = Label(master, text= "Welcome to the movie recommendation application! \n Please select the genre of the movie you would like to see.", fg='snow', bg='dark slate gray')
    self.label.pack(padx=25, pady=25)

    v = StringVar()

    c1 = self.radiobutton = Radiobutton(master, text = "Action", variable=v, value=1, bg='cyan3', command=self.reco1)
    c1.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10)

    c2 = self.radiobutton = Radiobutton(master, text = "Comedy", variable=v, value=2, bg='cyan3', command=self.reco2)
    c2.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10)

    c3 = self.radiobutton = Radiobutton(master, text = "Documentary", variable=v, value=3, bg='cyan3', command=self.reco3)
    c3.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10)

    c4 = self.radiobutton = Radiobutton(master, text = "Horror", variable=v, value=4, bg='cyan3', command=self.reco4)
    c4.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10)

    c5 = self.radiobutton = Radiobutton(master, text = "Romance", variable=v, value=5, bg='cyan3', command=self.reco5)
    c5.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10)


def reco1(self):
    y = StringVar()
    self.canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=200)
    self.canvas.pack( expand=YES, pady=20)
    gif1 = PhotoImage(file="movie1.gif")
    self.canvas.create_image(100,100,image=gif1)
    self.canvas.gif1 = gif1
    label = Message (root, textvariable=y)
    y.set("Would you like to watch this movie?")
    label.pack()
    self.radiobutton = Radiobutton(text = "YES", variable=y, command = self.choice1)
    self.radiobutton.pack(side=LEFT)
    self.radiobutton = Radiobutton(text = "NO", variable=y, command = self.choice2)
    self.radiobutton.pack(side=RIGHT)

def reco2(self):
    y = StringVar()
    self.canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=200)
    self.canvas.pack( expand=YES, pady=20)
    gif1 = PhotoImage(file="Movies/movie1.gif")
    self.canvas.create_image(100,100,image=gif1)
    self.canvas.gif1 = gif1
    label = Message (root, textvariable=y)
    y.set("Would you like to watch this movie?")
    label.pack()
    self.radiobutton = Radiobutton(text = "YES", variable=y, command = self.choice1)
    self.radiobutton.pack(side=LEFT)
    self.radiobutton = Radiobutton(text = "NO", variable=y, command = self.choice2)
    self.radiobutton.pack(side=RIGHT)
    reco2.loop()

def reco3(self):
    y = StringVar()
    self.canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=200)
    self.canvas.pack( expand=YES, pady=20)
    gif1 = PhotoImage(file="Movies/movie1.gif")
    self.canvas.create_image(100,100,image=gif1)
    self.canvas.gif1 = gif1
    label = Message (root, textvariable=y)
    y.set("Would you like to watch this movie?")
    label.pack()
    self.radiobutton = Radiobutton(text = "YES", variable=y, command = self.choice1)
    self.radiobutton.pack(side=LEFT)
    self.radiobutton = Radiobutton(text = "NO", variable=y, command = self.choice2)
    self.radiobutton.pack(side=RIGHT)

def reco4(self):
    y = StringVar()
    self.canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=200)
    self.canvas.pack( expand=YES, pady=20)
    gif1 = PhotoImage(file="Movies/movie1.gif")
    self.canvas.create_image(100,100,image=gif1)
    self.canvas.gif1 = gif1
    label = Message (root, textvariable=y)
    y.set("Would you like to watch this movie?")
    label.pack()
    self.radiobutton = Radiobutton(text = "YES", variable=y, command = self.choice1)
    self.radiobutton.pack(side=LEFT)
    self.radiobutton = Radiobutton(text = "NO", variable=y, command = self.choice2)
    self.radiobutton.pack(side=RIGHT)

def reco5(self):
    y = StringVar()
    self.canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=200)
    self.canvas.pack( expand=YES, pady=20)
    gif1 = PhotoImage(file="Movies/movie1.gif")
    self.canvas.create_image(100,100,image=gif1)
    self.canvas.gif1 = gif1
    label = Message (root, textvariable=y)
    y.set("Would you like to watch this movie?")
    label.pack()
    self.radiobutton = Radiobutton(text = "YES", variable=y, command = self.choice1)
    self.radiobutton.pack(side=LEFT)
    self.radiobutton = Radiobutton(text = "NO", variable=y, command = self.choice2)
    self.radiobutton.pack(side=RIGHT)

def choice1(self):
    messagebox.showinfo("Grab your popcorn and enjoy the movie!")
def choice2(self):
    messagebox.showinfo("I'm sorry, click the button to end the program and try again!")
    root.destroy()


root = Tk()
root.configure(bg='cyan3')
my_gui = movie1(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You create a new canvas with every choice. You might want to create it up front and just update the contents when a choice is made.